# What are the differences between carnitine forms?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, fat-metabolism

I've heard of L-carnitine, acetyl L-carnitine and L-carnitine L-tartrate. What form(s) occur in meat? What form does the human body manufacture?

Is L-carnitine just a shortened name for L-carnitine L-tartrate?

Comment: L-carnitine and L-tartrate are two separate compounds - though a lot of "nutritional supplements" will package them together and seem to refer to them like they are one compound.

Answer (score 3):

Carnitine tartrate is a salt between [carnitine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnitine) (cation) and tartrate (the conjugate base of [tartaric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartaric_acid), anion). So in this case, tartaric acid is not covalently bound to carnitine.

The salt formulation is a little tricky, because carnitine is itself a zwitterion at physiological pH (it has both a positive and negative charge) and so is overall uncharged in pure form. I think the tartrate salt is formed because tartaric acid is more acidic (first pKa = 2.89) than the carboxyl group of carnitine (pKa = 4.09), which leads carnitine to become protonated and therefore +1 charged in a concentrated mixture. The [formulation sold by Lonza](http://www.lonza.com/products-services/consumer-care/nutrition/human-nutrition/health-ingredients/carnipure.aspx) (which seems to be a major provider) appears to be a ratio of 2 cartinine (68%) to 1 tartrate (32%), which would indicate that tartrate acts as a -2 anion in this mixture (this is a bit surprising as the second pKa of tartaric acid has pKa = 4.40, but maybe I'm missing something).

You can recognize that this is a salt from the naming: the form tartr*ate* indicate a conjugate base of an acid (as in lactate, acetate), and when used in a two-component name like carnitine tartrate (or, sodium acetate) refers to a salt. On the other hand, a carboxylic acid covalently bound to another group is given the suffix *-yl*, so tartr*yl* carnitine would indicate tartaric acid bound to carnitine, as in fatty acid oxidation.

Answer (score -1):

[Carnitine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnitine) is a molecule that allows transport of carboxylic acids (including fatty acids) across mitochondrial membranes and is involved in fatty acid metabolism. Like many biomolecules it exists as the L-enantiomer in the cells. It can be coupled to any carboxylic acid and in that case is called acyl-carnitine. [L-Carnitine L-tartrate](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-drug/def/l-carnitine-l-tartrate) is a drug formulation and is a mixture of L-carnitine and L-tartarate (tartarate is not covalently coupled to tartaric acid).